# 30 year vs 10 year Fixed Rate Mortgage

Tags: mortgage

Let's say you're going to apply for a mortgage and two of your options are getting a 10 year, fixed rate mortgage or a 30 year, fixed rate mortgage. As is standard, you'll have a lower interest rate and lower payments (say 4.50% and $1500/month) for the 30 year than you will for the 10 year (say 5.00% and $2000/month). In both cases, you do not receive a penalty for early payments.

My question is, is there a reason you might choose the 10 year over the 30 year? It seems to me that you can choose the 30 year and pay it off as early as you can, while taking advantage of the lower interest rate and the lower monthly bill in the event you can't overpay that month. All things being equal, it seems to me the 30-year is always a better choice to me.

Comment: It is not standard for 10-year *rates* to be higher than 30-year rates.  It is standard for the monthly payment to be higher.  You may be including costs other than the interest rate in this calculation.  For example, PMI, property taxes, closing costs, etc.  Also, consider adding a country tag to your question.  Your interest rate examples seem high for the US.  A quick search suggests 3.6% APR for the 30 and 3.1% for a 10.

Comment: I've never heard of a 30 year having a lower interest rate - I've never even heard of a 30 year having the *same* interest rate.

Comment: @neminem It seems I've gotten things backwards. Sorry for the confusion. Mortgages are an unknown beast for me and this was something I was simply curious about.

Comment: Haven't we just had a question like this a few weeks ago... taking a quick look.

Comment: Also see http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66318/why-are-30-year-mortgages-seen-as-unwise-if-you-can-pay-off-the-loan-in-a-short

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your assumption is wrong, but your conclusion is correct.

Typically, shorter terms have *lower* interest rates (you assumed the inverse, which *can* happen but is uncommon), mostly because the shorter the term, the lower the risk is.

Another reason to pick the shorter term would be purely psychological - although you *could* simply overpay the longer term mortgage, most people struggle to stick with that. It is quite easy to find a reason every month to skip 'just one more month' and use the money for something else - and then end up with 29.5 years after all.

Comment: Great answer. The only thing I would add is why the interest rates are lower:  underwriters are assuming less risk.  But I bet you knew that.